# Handling LostFocus event for control in DataGrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, event-handling, visual-studio-lightswitch

I need to write an event procedure to handle the LostFocus event of the selected control (a textbox) in a DataGrid in a VS Lightswitch Silverlight application.  How do I do that, given that LS doesn't provide a ControlAvailable property on controls that are in a control collection?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you have to add an `EventTrigger` for `LostFocus` to the cell template. But to be honest, I can't be bothered to write up all the xaml that is involved at the moment. Maybe you help me out and present a nicely formatted xaml snippet that shows the columnConfigurations and cellTemplates and I add my part to it.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Martin. It seems that you're talking about a regular Silverlight app, whereas I'm referring to doing this from within a VS Lightswitch application. Is that correct?

Comment: That's correct, I don't know in what ways Lightswitch and regular SL differ.